# Is "There are no absolute truths" a paradox?

Tags: logic

I was wondering if the statement:

> > There are no absolute truths

is a paradox or, rather, can be considered at face value.

Also, this is just a naive guess, could this statement be related to Russel's Paradox where if:

$\Omega$ = {set of absolute truths}, then $\Omega$ would not contain itself. (Please have mercy on my inept attempt at set theory.)

Comment: If the statement is just plain false, where is the paradox?

Comment: If one were shown a *formal* version of this, then one could likely provide an answer.

Comment: Personally I am convinced that the statement is false. Accepting it as an absolute truth leads to a contradiction.

Comment: @DanielFischer Stopped me in my tracks. Thanks.